# Weird compilation error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've got a weird error with the next code compilation.

```
using System;

public class Tree<T> : IComparable<Tuple<double, T>>
{
    public int CompareTo(Tuple<double, T> other)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of
>   the generic type definition. Parameter name: instantiation.

- The error occurs only in my project. The same code successfully compiles in new project.
- Replacing `Tuple<double, T>` to `Tuple<T, T>` also gives successfull compilation.

Comment: I assume there's no other code in that project?

Comment: Maybe you have a custom `Tuple` type somewhere...? What is the target framework in your project?

Comment: @Avi there is a lot of other code in that project. Project without other code compiles successfully.

Comment: @nemesv there is no my own `Tuple`. Target framework is .NET v4.

Comment: The mentioned error is most probably thrown by a `Type.MakeGenericType` call. So the question is do you have some code which runs on compile which can call `Type.MakeGenericType` e.g do you use PostSharp or other IL waving compoment, do you have some T4 templates which regenerated on compile etc?